# Type based on .env file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, environment-variables

In **react** project, do you think of any possible way of assigning a type to a variable based on `.env` (or any other file) at the compile time?

I have a type `let X: A|B|C|null = null`. I assign the A, B, or C to the `X` based on the variable stored in the `.env`. The reason I want to do that is so the hover or "on click" on the `X` shows me/forwards me to the correct class.

I've come up with no solid solution yet

Comment: You appear to want your IDE to load this `.env` and include it in IntelliSense, or whatever it's called in your IDE. That's more a question to the developers of your IDE, but to my knowledge no IDE can do this today.

Comment: TypeScript performs **static** analysis of your source code. If you would like for the values that currently exist in your `.env` file to participate in type-checking, then you should move them from the `.env` file and into your source code directly (e.g. export them from a new module called `env.ts`).

Answer (score -1):

Environment variables are read in run-time

TypeScript doesn't exist anymore in run-time

So **it's not possible**

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question so it is solely focused on compile time

Comment: As [currently written](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74855316/1), this is not an answer, but a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). See [answer].